# Finding the name of the geometry column for QgsVectorLayers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, geometry, geopackage, qgsvectorlayer

I have a `QgsVectorLayer` whose data source is a vector GeoPackage file. How can I find the name of its geometry column?

[It is possible to use `ogr` to get it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395189/cannot-get-geometry-column-name-from-geopandas/395192#395192), but I am looking for a native PyQGIS approach without additional imports or separately loading the dataset again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`QgsDataSourceUri`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsDataSourceUri.html#adae633790385a2839fc63f05f0757a5b) :

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.dataProvider().uri().geometryColumn()
```

Edit, after reading comments. It doesn't work for GPKG.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a `dataProvider` property either, that shows the geometry column.

As a temporary hack, I would use GDAL OGR:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
source = layer.source().split('|')
gpkg = source[0]
lname = source[1].split('=')[1]

conn = ogr.Open(gpkg)
l = conn.GetLayerByName(lname)
geomName = l.GetGeometryColumn()
print(geomName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerUtils

v_layer = iface.activeLayer()

conn = QgsMapLayerUtils.databaseConnection(v_layer)
true_layer_name = v_layer.source().split('layername=')[-1]
table = conn.table('', true_layer_name)

print(table.geometryColumn())
```