# Get the name of the geometry column(s) of a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, geodataframe

Sometime, the name of the geometry column of a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) is simply not 'geometry' but a custom name which in some situations cannot be known in advance because it may have been defined dynamically prior to when we need to access it.

So, is there something more simple/elegant/pythonic than the following snippet to get the name of the geometry columns in a [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/)' GeoDataFrame?

```py
gdf.dtypes[gdf.dtypes=="geometry"].index.values.tolist()[0]

'custom_name'
```

Notice the `[0]` because the list is having only one element, but if your GeoDataFrame is having more than one geometry column, then you may want to fine tune that to suit your needs.

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395189/getting-geometry-column-name-from-geopandas) topic is not helping much as I'd like to stay within GeoPandas.

Answer (score 1):

The best result I have had so far is this one:

```py
list(gdf.select_dtypes('geometry'))[0]
```

And I think it's OK but if there was a more direct method I would be glad to hear about it.

In the case of a GeoDataFrame with multiple geometry columns, as there should normally be one *active* geometry column, one can get this particular one as follows (see at the bottom for the rare case of a GeoDataFrame with multiple *active* geometry columns):

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

d = {
  'col1': ['name1', 'name2'],
  'fancy': [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)],
  'custom': [Point(3, 4), Point(5, 6)],
}

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d)


gdf 
>: 
    col1        fancy       custom
0  name1  POINT (1 2)  POINT (3 4)
1  name2  POINT (2 1)  POINT (5 6)
```

Currently, none of the column is seen a a geometry column:

```py
gdf.dtypes
>: 
col1      object
fancy     object
custom    object
dtype: object
```

At this stage, if we use the method shown above to extract the geometry column name on the GeoDataFrame, it throws an error:

```py
gdf.dtypes
>: 
col1      object
fancy     object
custom    object
dtype: object

# running this naturally raises an error:
list(gdf.select_dtypes('geometry'))[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_369762/3000512511.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    list(gdf.select_dtypes('geometry'))[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Because the list is actually empty:

```py
gdf.select_dtypes('geometry')

>: 
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1]
```

That's why we need to actually "set" the geometry column, i.e. we mark it as *active*:

```py
gdf.set_geometry('fancy', inplace=True, crs=4326,)

gdf.dtypes
>: 
col1        object
fancy     geometry
custom      object
dtype: object
```

So mow the previous code returns the active geometry column:

```py
list(gdf.select_dtypes('geometry'))[0]
>: 'fancy'
```

But fortunately, you can set more than one *active* geometry column (although this is not the most common case):

```py
gdf.set_geometry('custom', inplace=True, crs=4326,)

gdf.dtypes
>: 
col1        object
fancy     geometry
custom    geometry
dtype: object
```

Then, because the list of `geometry` columns has more than one element now, you will have to manually figure out which element you want:

```py
list(gdf.select_dtypes('geometry'))
>: ['fancy', 'custom']
```

Answer (score 1):

In geopandas 0.14.2, there is an easier way to find the active geometry column.  (I'm not sure what version this started in).

`gdf.geometry.name`

You can also use the attribute `gdf.geometry` to always get the current geometry column data.

Only one geometry column can be "active" at any given moment, though you can have as many columns containing the `dtype == 'geometry'` as you want.

See more details [in the docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#geodataframe).